# Regex Extract in Google SQL

Tags: sql, regex

I have a string in my table that looks like this:

BA - GH: 236274637437 - GH Name: HHG PRIO BHTG SAMP RAND - 6384 - 38k - Own: dhgfhdh

How can I regex extract only the contents in GH name?
In other words, how can I extract only up to a certain point in the string?

This is my code for extracting Own

```
SELECT COLNAM, 
REGEX_EXTRACT(COLNAME, r'\bOwn.*\b') AS own
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Your regex extracts `Own:` as part of a match. Anyway, what does it have to do with the problem? What are the current pattern requirements and what is your issue with that pattern?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you want anything that is between "GH Name: " and the first " -":

```
(?<=GH Name: ).+?(?= -)
```

Comment: RE2 does not support lookarounds.